# How to copy a file to swarm file system (fuse aka swarmfs)?

Tags: swarm

I have mounted a swarm file system (fuse aka swarmfs). It shows the previously uploaded file (using 'swarm up file1.txt' command) in it.

However, I cannot copy any file inside it. It is throwing permission related error. I am using linux 'cp file.txt swarmFs/.' command for copying inside this directory. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The initial version of fuse was read-only. You can look at the file permission to confirm this (700). From version 1.6 it is both read and write. If you can upgrade it to geth version 1.6 +, this should work